How to Monitor User Import Actions and Enforce Subscription Limits Using Firebase, Flet, and Python?
I have developed a desktop software using Flet and Python that integrates with the Shopify API to create new products.
I would like to monitor the import actions of my users and implement a subscription-based limit (e.g., 100 items per month). How can I track these actions per user and enforce the import limits automatically?
I am using Firebase for authentication and other functionalities. Do you have any suggestions for platforms or methods to monitor all imports per user and automatically block imports when limits are reached? I was thinking of using a database to log these actions, but I am open to other ideas.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You added the stripe-payments tag but made no mention of Stripe in your question and seem to focus on Shopify's API.

my mistake, i saw some things about stripe, on subscriptions idea that i mentioned
